# How to include the information in a checkbox in a web api?

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I have a group of filtering multi-select lists and each of them have a checkbox in "exclude" them.  I would like to know how I can put logic in for that checkbox so that when it is checked that filter will be excluded from the final filtering logic.

I am pretty new at .net core and web api so I am sorry if this is elementary.

What I have tried was to pass a boolean into the parameters and it did not work for me
[image: exclude text boxes in question]

This is how the UI looks for the application.  The checkboxes highlighted are the ones I am having trouble with.  If they are checked I need to exclude that value from the filter.  If you would like to throw in how to pass the multi-select that would be great too but not as crucial as the checkboxes

Comment: Can you show us some few codes you made and how you implement the checkbox on the UI side?

Comment: I am working with another team that is building the UI in angular.